# MySQL da error de sintaxis al ejecutar un procedimiento

Tags: mysql, condiciones, plsql

tengo la siguiente query en MySQL

```
delimiter //
create procedure notas(nota float)
    begin
        if (nota >= 0.0 and < 5.0) then
            select 'Insuficiente' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 5.0 and < 6.0) then
            select 'Aprobado' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 6.0 and nota < 7.0) then
            select 'Bien' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 7.0 and nota < 9.0) then
            select 'Notable' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 9.0 and nota <= 10.0) then
            select 'Sobresaliente' as Nota;
        else
            select 'Nota inválida' as Error;
        end if;
    end//
delimiter ;
```

Me da un error de sintaxis, he probado quitando los paréntesis de los condicionales, también he probado a poner elif o else if en lugar de elseif pero nada de lo que he intentado funciona. ¿Alguien ve que tengo mal? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Prueba a quitarles el ";" al final de cada línea excepto al delimiter ;

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, pero no ha funcionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
delimiter //
create procedure notas(nota float)
    begin
        if (nota >= 0.0 and nota < 5.0) then  --  <-- error aquí
            select 'Insuficiente' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 5.0 and nota < 6.0) then -- <-- y aquí
            select 'Aprobado' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 6.0 and nota < 7.0) then
            select 'Bien' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 7.0 and nota < 9.0) then
            select 'Notable' as Nota;
        elseif (nota >= 9.0 and nota <= 10.0) then
            select 'Sobresaliente' as Nota;
        else
            select 'Nota inválida' as Error;
        end if;
    end//
delimiter ;
```

Faltaba la variable tras el `AND`

Comment: Sí, ese era el problema, no había visto que faltaba la variable, muchas gracias

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)